# Write the equations as a single equation in $x$ and $y$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Given the parameterization,

\begin{cases}
x=at\cos 2t\\
y=a\sin t
\end{cases}

I need to write $y$ (or $x$) as a function of $x$ (or $y$).

What I tried, there was always the variable $t$, so I isolated $t$,

$$t=\frac{ax}{a^2-2y^2}$$

But when I substitute I always come in $x=x$ or $y=y$. Could someone give me a hint on how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is pretty messy.

$$t = \arcsin {\frac{y}{a}}$$
$$ x = at \cos(2t)= at(1-2\sin^2t) = a \arcsin \frac{y}{a} \left(1-2\left(\frac{y}{a}\right)^2\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, could you also help me write $y$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: I actually don't think that is doable in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Didn't answer the question, but upvote for attempt

Comment: Nevermind, you did answer the question, didnt realize $a$ was a constant, good job